# Adding Calculated Column in Pandas Dataframe via Indexing Column #s

Tags: python, pandas

Currently building a simple Customer Lifetime Value calculator program for marketing purposes. For a portion of the program, I give the user the option to `import a CSV file via pd.read_csv` to allow calculations across multiple customer records. I designate the required order of the CSV data in notes included in the output window.

The `imported CSV should have 4 inputs per row`. Building off of this, I want to `create a new column in the dataframe that multiplies columns 1-4`. Operating under the assumption that some users will include headers (that will vary per user) while others will not, is there a way I can create the new calculated column based on column # rather than header?

Beginner here. None of the answers I have found have worked for me/been similar to my situation.

Comment: If you want to refer columns via their indices, you need to use `iloc`. For example, `df.iloc[:, 0]` gives you the first column, `df.iloc[:, :4]` gives you the first four columns and so on...

Comment: Tracking--I believe I understand how to reference these indices via iloc. But then how do I utilize this format in a multiplication function for a new column?

Comment: Are you asking the method for the multiplication? `df['new_col'] = df.iloc[:, :4].prod(axis=1)` If not, please add a sample input and desired output in your question.

Comment: `prod` worked. Thank you.